# How to prevent converting of double with high value?

Tags: c#, double, number-formatting, globalization, tryparse

I have got a function which checks if a `string` is a `double` and if so the value has to be rounded to two digits and returned as `string`. If not an `empty string` will be returned. This works fine for the most cases. But for the upper border, the value is rounded to the next integer which is wrong. How can I force that the value will not be rounded?

Upper border: `9999999999999999.9900000000000000`

Expected value: `9999999999999999.99`

Given value: `10000000000000000`

```cs
public string MyConvertFunction(string param)
{ 
    double result;

    if(System.Double.TryParse(param, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), out result)) {
        if(result == 0.0) return "";
        return result.ToString("0.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
    }

    return "";
}
```

It seems that the rounding is at the `TryParse` part. Therefore something like this

```cs
double x = Math.Truncate(myDoubleValue * 100) / 100;
```

Not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `double` can hold about 15 to 16 significant digits, and your huge number is larger than that, so that's why your value gets rounded.  So, there is no solution to your problem.  You have two options:

1. Live with the fact that you cannot represent so large numbers without loss of precision.  As you keep adding digits to the left end of the number, some digits on the right end of the number will not be meaningful anymore.
2. Stop using `double` and start using `decimal` instead.  This data type performs worse than `double`, but it has a much greater precision.

Reference for decimal: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal

Comment: Glad to be of help!  C-:=

Answer (score 0):

Just check the number of characters before decimal sign. In your case, the maximum number would be 16 (if I counted correctly :)).

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with any rounding in `TryParse` itself. This issue is due to how numbers are represented by `System.Double` and the limitations it has.

Try stepping through the following code:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var d = 9999999999999999.99;
    }
}
```

And inspect the value of `d`. What value does it have?

`double` simply doesn't have enough precision to represent that number and it is rounded off to `1e+16`.

If `9999999999999999.99` is a reasonable value in your application then consider using `decimal` instead of `double`.